# Parsing keyed/valued nested JSON at different levels using TypeScript in Node

Tags: node.js, json, typescript, parsing

I got some data that I have to parse at different levels to fetch it and keep a similar structure in the way it is formated. I'm using TypeScript in the Node environment (Google Cloud) which I'm using for my current project. I'm quite new to this language and environement, I'm sicking guidance on the language feature aspect not on the data processing part.

The data that I have as input is in XML and is presented as the following:

```
<item>
    <key xsi:type="xsd:string">intermedite_key</key>
    <value xsi:type="ns2:Map">
        <item>
            <key xsi:type="xsd:string">Key_parse_first_level_1</key>
            <value xsi:type="ns2:Map">
                <item>
                    <key xsi:type="xsd:string">intermedite_key</key>
                    <value xsi:type="ns2:Map">
                        <item>
                            <key xsi:type="xsd:string">Key_parse_second_level_1</key>
                            <value xsi:type="ns2:Map">
                                <item>
                                    <key xsi:type="xsd:int">intermedite_key</key>
                                    <value xsi:type="ns2:Map">
                                        <item>
                                            <key xsi:type="xsd:string">Key_1</key>
                                            <value xsi:type="xsd:string">DataToParse</value>
                                        </item>
                                        <item>
                                            <key xsi:type="xsd:string">Key_2</key>
                                            <value xsi:type="xsd:string">DataToParse</value>
                                        </item>
                                    </value>
                                </item>
                            </value>
                        </item>
                        <item>
                            <key xsi:type="xsd:string">Key_parse_second_level_2</key>
                            <value xsi:type="ns2:Map">
                                <item>
                                    <key xsi:type="xsd:int">intermedite_key</key>
                                    <value xsi:type="ns2:Map">
                                        <item>
                                            <key xsi:type="xsd:string">Key_parse_third_level_1</key>
                                            <value xsi:type="xsd:string">DataToFetch</value>
                                        </item>
                                        <item>
                                            <key xsi:type="xsd:string">Key_parse_third_level_2</key>
                                            <value xsi:type="xsd:string">DataToFetch</value>
                                        </item>
                                        </item>
                                    </value>
                                </item>
                            </value>
                        </item>
                    </value>
                </item>
            </value>
        </item>
        <item>
            <key xsi:type="xsd:string">Key_parse_first_level_2>
            <value xsi:type="ns2:Map">
                <item>
                    <key xsi:type="xsd:string">intermedite_key</key>
                    <value xsi:type="ns2:Map">
                        <item>
                            <key xsi:type="xsd:string">Key_parse_second_level_1</key>
                            <value xsi:type="ns2:Map">
                                <item>
                                    <key xsi:type="xsd:int">intermedite_key</key>
                                    <value xsi:type="ns2:Map">
                                        <item>
                                            <key xsi:type="xsd:string">Key_parse_third_level_1</key>
                                            <value xsi:type="xsd:string">DataToFetch</value>
                                        </item>
                                        <item>
                                            <key xsi:type="xsd:string">Key_parse_third_level_2</key>
                                            <value xsi:type="xsd:string">DataToFetch</value>
                                        </item>
                                    </value>
                                </item>
                            </value>
                        </item>
                    </value>
                </item>
            </value>
        </item>
        <item>
        
        ... Other items
        
        </item>
    </value>
</item>
```

I have managed to write this piece of code which works to parse the first level but at the second level:

```
/*Converts the XMl into a an object with 'fast-xml-parser'*/
const getRawResponseJSON = parser.parse(XMLDataToConvert);

const FisrtLevel = getRawResponseJSON['item']['value']['item']

Object(FisrtLevel).forEach((FisrtLevelValues: any) => {

  const SecondLevel = Object.entries(FisrtLevelValues.value.item.value.item)

  SecondLevel.forEach((SecondLevelValues: any) => {

    console.log("value - " + SecondLevelValues);
    
    });
    
});
```

Those are the console out-puts for Key_parse_second_level_1 :

```
value - 0,[object Object] 

value - 1,[object Object]
```

And for Key_parse_second_level_2:

```
value - value,[object Object]
```

It seems that Key_parse_second_level_1 values aren't "aligned" with Key_parse_second_level_2 and when I go deeper I don't have the expected results for keys and values. Therefore I have different questions, was using Object classes a good idea for this case (I was enticed to use them for the keys and entries methods) ? Would an Array class have been better to use ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my issue by doing this :

```
const SecondLevel = Object.entries(FisrtLevelValues.value.item.value.item)

Object.keys(SecondLevel).forEach((SecondLevelKeys: any) => {

    let SecondLevelValues: any;
          
          if(String(SecondLevelKeys).match("value")){
  
            return;
  
          } else if (String(SecondLevelKeys).match("key")){
 
            SecondLevelValues = SecondLevel['value']['item']['value']['item'];
  
          } else if (String(SecondLevelKeys).match(/[0-9]/)) {
          

            SecondLevelValues = SecondLevel[SecondLevelKeys]['value']['item']['value']['item'];

          }

          Object.keys(SecondLevelValues).forEach((ThirdLevelKeys) => {
            
            const getKey = SecondLevelValues[ThirdLevelKeys]['key'];
            const getValues = SecondLevelValues[ThirdLevelKeys]['value'];

            ...

          });
    
});
```

At the SecondLevel the if is used to filter out the "value" key because Object.key() gave two results, "value" and "key" (which is the sole needed for my cause). The last else if filters keys by number because when having multiple items Object.key() gave me numbers as item index.

In case it helps someone.